# PHP How to return or exit with an array?

Tags: php, arrays, exit

This may seem like a simple question but I have searched for an answer and come across call backs and a few different things but surely there is a simple way to do this.

I have a function in a class

that uses an iterative process so i end up with an array:

```
$msg[$i]
```

I want to exit the function with that array returned to main script

```
exit($msg[])
```

but will only return for example `$msg[1]` or `$msg[$i]` the last iteration I'd like to get the whole array without manually typing each one defeats the point of the iterative process

Comment: return $msg; ... thats all there is to it

Comment: $msg[] is when you want to push items into the array. Ex: `$msg[] = 2;`

Answer (score 3):

use return instead exit

```
return $msg;
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using `return $msg;` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to return an array, you return the variable name of the array.  This is really a pointer to the first element in the array.

This is an example of how to return an array:

```
function dofoo() {
    $msg["a"] = "Foo";
    $msg["b"] = "Bar";
    $msg["c"] = "Baz";
    return $msg;
}

$returned_array = dofoo();
```

Under the hood what happens is: `return $msg;` returns a pointer to the first element of the array. `$returned_array = dofoo();` allocates enough memory for the returned array and stores it in `$returned_array`.

Comment: `pointer to the first element` could you explain this? Are you saying that if `msg` were a global, it would be referenced?

Comment: Each index of an array points to the place in memory where that value is stored.  The variable name of the array points to the first element in the array, and therefore allows access to the entire array.